# SAP Cloud Platform - can you use existing on-Premise Fiori Logins

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

​We are building an app on our SCP Trail account.
By default the login to this is our SCP trail account ID (begins with an S number).

In practice though, existing users of our on-Premise Fiori will need to login to the app using there existing Fiori login (as they wont have SCP logins).

How is this setup?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect your SCP to your on-premise identity repository. Either that or propagate the SCP account to your on-premise backend system. Both are standard methods documented by SAP. However, Identity Management is not part of the trial landscape so you should subscribe to a productive account first.

...and you should think twice about your strategy for this hybrid scenario as you already have some Fiori on-premise. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: We current don't have SSO setup, so until then I don't think this i feasible. Why do we need to think twice?

Comment: Most likely, you want to launch your new SCP app in your on-premise Fiori launchpad. Or, the opposite, switching to the SCP Fiori Launchpad. Just make sure it's a decision where you evaluate both approaches for your environment. Lot's of pitfalls where things can go wrong!

Comment: It too big a change to move all existing systems to the cloud, and the new app is mobile so needs to be accessible from the cloud.